# Returning a record from list without a foreign key

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I am trying to grab a record by ID, however I am getting error in the function `getPersonById` when I don't provide `rs.getString("school")`. But I do not want to display that because it is a foreign key. How do I get around that? Can I maybe create a new object? Can someone advice? Thanks.

```java
    public class Person {
        
        private String name;
        private UUID id;
        private UUID school;
        
        public(UUID id, String name, UUID school) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.school = school;
        }
      
     ...getters
    }
```

```java
 public int getPersonById(UUID id) {
        String sql = "SELECT id, name from people where id = ?";
        List<Person> people = jdbcTemplate.query(sql,(rs,i)->{
          return new Person(
            rs.getObject("id", java.util.UUID.class),
            rs.getString("name")   
);      
}, id);
   return people.stream().findFirst();  
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Do you want the field or not? Either provide it or remove it.

Comment: Your constructor definition has 'school' as parameter. Your call the constructor without the parameter. You need to decide what do you exactly want: to have constructor with 2 parameters only or to call existing constructor with 3 parameters.

Comment: @shmosel no, but I need it when Im inserting a Person, so I can't remove it form constructor.

Comment: So use a different class. Or create a subclass. Or set the parameter to null. Or set the field to null. Or use some dummy value. Or load it but don't display it. It's up to you.